# When I scroll UP on mobile, it jumps straight to the top

Tags: javascript, wordpress, scroll

This is an old website, build on WordPress but there is a bug only on mobile devices ( cant replicate with dev-tools ). When you are scrolling down, sometimes it automatically brings you up at start of the page, sometimes it's Ok but after scrolling a little bit UP, again it jumps to the start of the page. 
Could someone please help or guide me on  that.

Website -> [here](http://ashleylouisejames.littlevitamindevelopment.com/)

Comment: Older websites might not support the newer browsers like safari or edge

Comment: Im wondering if users are tapping the scroll to top area on the bottom right on mobile by mistake?